# $|\operatorname{Re}((2a+ib)^{2n+1})|\neq b$ for coprime $2a,b$ and $n>1$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> Assume $n>1$ is natural and set
>   $$f_n(a,b):=\operatorname{Re}((2a+ib)^{2n+1}).$$
>   Prove that for every coprime pair $2a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$: $|f_n(a,b)|>b$.

Note that we have $b|f_n(a,b)$ so the only thing required is to show the inequality is strong. Noting that $|f_n(a,b)|$ behaves exponential (from checking specific values) in $n$ it seems trivial, yet a proof eludes me.

We can expand it:
$$f_n(a,b)=b\sum_{k=0}^n{{2n+1}\choose{2k}}(-4)^ka^{2k}b^{2(n-k)}$$
But nothing from here.

Induction seems impossible due to frequent sign changes; Stirling's bound gives no help either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You write $f_n(a,b) = b^{2n+1} + b*4*N$, with $(b,2)=1$ and $n>1$. Are not you done (for $b\neq 1$)? For $b=1$ you can pick $a=0$ and the statement is false.

Comment: $N$ can be negative and b is odd so it does not help.

Comment: For $a=1$, $b=0$ we get $(2a+bi)^{2n+1}=i(-1)^n$ so the real part is zero and not $\pm 1$

Comment: Certainly $N$ can be negative, nevertheless $f_n(a,b) \neq b$ precisely because $b$ is odd (if $b\neq 1$). I realize now that your title has a different question than the question itself. Are you interested in $f_n(a,b) \neq b$ or $f_n(a,b) >b$? My comment addresses the former.

Comment: They are equivelent, the weak inequality is given from the expansion,
and setting $b=3$, $n=2$, $N=20$ refutes yor claim.

Comment: @Omer Rosler. I have a problem: $f_n(a,0)$ is the real part of $(2a)^{2n+1}$, so if $a\not =0$, it is not $0$. Hence $b$ cannot be a factor of $f_n(a,b)$.

Comment: a is coprime to b so if $b=0$ then $a=\pm 1$ and $f_n(1,0)=0$

Comment: @Omer Rosler: $f_n(1,0)$ is the real part of $2^{2n+1}$. It is not $0$. (I think that perhaps your formula giving $f_n(a,b)$ is not correct).

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, in this case $gcd(2a,b)=2$

Comment: Maybe it can be attacked algebrically, at least for $n=2$; we have $f_2(a,b)=80a^4-40a^2b^2+b^4$, if we could find a number field where this describes a norm of some element that depends on $a,b$ we can use Dirichlet's Unit theorem to find all units (and hopefully show that there is no solution).